# Using SAPI with C#, how to have a DLL that uses SAPI be able to check if a voice is still going while using ASYNC?

Tags: c#, accessibility, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm trying to make a TTS DLL using SAPI. Passing text to be spoken is easy enough, but I'm having a problem. My secondary program has no way of knowing when TTS is done if I use ASYNC. I need to use ASYNC so the user can continue to use the program while TTS is still going, and so they would have the option to call the DLL again to stop it early. Using non async would make my secondary program freeze until TTS is finished speaking.

I tried to take two approaches:

1. I tried to use the speech synth STATE command. But it doesn't check if any TTS voice is running, only if a supplied one is running. So being able to call the ASYNC function, then a second later call the STATE function doesn't seem possible since I can't see a way to pass information from the first function to the second with a secondary program in the middle.
2. A work around would be if I could know exactly how long the voice is going to be speaking at the time I call it through a DLL. But while I can call the RATE, that doesn't seem to help me calculate how long it's going to be speaking.

This secondary program that is calling this DLL is not in C#, so can't simply  pass around the synthesizer info that is created.

What can I look into for this?

Comment: Why aren't you using [SAPI events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720165(v=vs.85)) to determine when TTS is done?  Package it up in your DLL, and off you go...  I'd also recommend moving to the [System.Media.SpeechSynthesis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer?view=winrt-22000) APIs, instead of SAPI, as it integrates better with Windows settings...

Comment: @EricBrown 

So for the events, the C# version at least looks like it needs to be passed the information on the synth voice and then it can check if that specific voice is working. But as a DLL I don't see how I can pass that information from the dll, to my program, then back to the DLL. If there is a way I guess that is what I'm missing.

As for not using UWP, compatibility is a problem. I'm also looking into making my secondary program accept UWP DLLs, which if I can my problems are solved. But for right now I think I might just need to figure out how to make sapi work.

Comment: Why would the DLL need to pass any info back to the calling program?   The DLL knows what voice, etc, it's using.  Just export a function "IsTTSDoneYet" or the like.

Comment: @EricBrown Maybe I'm misunderstanding and that's the problem. Here is how I'm aware this works. 
You get ready to use SAPI with this:

 SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
Talk with this:
 synth.Speak("talking");
Calling with this:
double vState = (double)synth.State;


Then I can check state with this.

            int vState = (int)synth.State;
            return vState;

But to be able to check the status of it, I'm under the impression I need to have the synth object that I created. But if I call the DLL later asking for a status update I don't have that.

Comment: You haven't shared your interface, so it's hard to comment.   However, you can use [IntPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=net-5.0) to encapsulate your C# object and pass that around to retain your class object.